# HP-UX Unix add existing array string elements to total string with for loop starting from defined element

Tags: arrays, shell, for-loop, hp-ux

In shell script (!/bin/sh) I have array elements:

```
u[1]="someString"
u[2]="anotherString"
u[3]="aThirdString"
u[4]="aFourhString"
```

I want to build a new string, which will display the string values of u array elements that I want and separated by semi-column (;).  I want to do the following:

```
totalString=""
for k in {2..4}; do
totalString+="${u[k]};"
done
```

But I cannot make it to work. First of all, for some reason k is interpreted like a {2..4} at the above, instead of evaluating the value of u[k] every time to finally display the desired:

```
anotherString;aThirdString;aFourhString
```

Note that the example array elements are not always the same as above example. I could have more than 4, or less.  I am counting and define them with other part of code and I want to display some of them only at the total new string.

Comment: After some further investigation:  a) The above is possible only using bash script.  b) With Shell script, only the while loop can do the job, using manual counter increment ( i=(($i+1)) )

Comment: Hardly could anybody help you if you do not include the right tag as `shell`.